# Expression Builder Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, type-conversion, string-concatenation

I am trying to build a an expression in Access 2010 that takes a number from a field called barcodeNumber and turns that number into a string then takes that string and concatenates an * to the beginning and an * to the end. This is what I have:

```
"*" & CStr([barcodeNumber]) & "*"
```

But this is returning:

```
*Error 0*
```

What does that error mean? And how can I accomplish what I want?

Comment: I'm not sure but, could you try this to see if it works:
iif(isnull([barcodeNumber]), "\*0\*", "\*" & CStr([barcodeNumber]) & "\*")

Comment: @IgorTurman That's still giving me the same error.

Comment: I tried this: "*"+[barcodeNumber]+"*" and got this: #Type! as an error.

Comment: I wish I had Access at work :). "+" would not work. If you simplify to just Cstr([barcodeNumber]), does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up doing this:

```
= "*" & [barcodeNumber] & "*"
```

Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Error 0 means "no error". Check this out (any of the replies): bytes.com/topic/access/answers/523300-error-0-20-a

In case your error is due to NULL values:

```
"*" & CStr(IIf(IsNull([barcodeNumber]), 0, [barcodeNumber])) & "*"
```